# Javascript: Variable declaration in node.js HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks

Node.js: I am iterating through the contents of title2 using for loop. But to make the div tag unique, I am using the `{{var i=0;}}` it gives the following error `expected variable end`. I also tried `{% var i = 0; %}` but that too doesnt seem to work I have put the end tag but it does not seem to work. I might mostly be putting the wrong end tag but I cannot figure out the right one. Can I know if this is the right way to declare a variable and end it? Also if this is the right way to increment the variable in the HTML file?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div><h4>Python Examples</h4>
    {% for contentPackage in contentPackages %}
    {% for ex in contentPackage.title2 %}
    {{var i=0;}}


    <div class="contentPackage col-md-4">
        <h5 style="font-size: 15px;padding-left: 3px" class="packageTitle bg-primary">{{ ex['topic_name'] }}
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-link" onclick="javascript:$('#pane'+i).panel('open')"> [Open</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-link" onclick="javascript:$('#pane'+i).panel('close')">Close] </a>
        </h5>

        <div id="pane{{i}}"  closed="true" openAnimation="slide" closeAnimation="slide" class="easyui-panel" title="{{ ex['topic_name'] }}" style="padding:2px;">

            <div class="contentPackageMain">
                <div class="teaserContent">
                    <ol>
                       <p>Something</p>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{i++}}
    {{endvar}}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some key information: What templating system are you using here?

Comment: i am using the `nunjucks` templating system

Comment: Instead of your `i` try using built-in index `{{ loop.index }}` ,https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for

Comment: Thank you for the resource...looks like thats what I needed...but due to some reason it doesnt seem to work...am I doing it right in the onclick method?
`onclick="javascript:$('#pane'+((loop.index).toString())).panel('open')"`

Comment: Okay I figured that out...it should be something like this...
`onclick="javascript:$('#pane'+'{{loop.index}}').panel('open')"`
thanks a lot...hope i could upvote your answer